# Is this a water leak or condensation in the wall around my dryer vent?

Tags: walls, leak, dryer, moisture, humidity

I pulled my dryer out yesterday to clean the vent and tubing. When I moved the dryer I noticed what looked like a huge wet stain around the vent connection that leads to my attic. There appears to be a water stain about 2 ft above that as well. Directly above the vent connection in the wall, the wall is soft and wet.

We tried turning off the water meter for 3 hours and there was no change to the meter, which indicates no leak. I left a fan blowing on the wall for about 18 hours now and the stain is less visible and all drywall is dry to the touch today. Which makes me think maybe it isn’t a leak? But, my laundry room backs up to a bathroom so I’m concerned.

It’s $350 for someone to confirm I have a leak so I'd rather not pay if someone can help identify the issue.

I also feel that I need to add I live in Florida where it is very humid.  [image]

Comment: Have you checked for leaking roof?  Condensation usually caused by cold water pipes in warm space.  Is vent going to outside or ends inside attic?

Comment: My first guess would be that the dryer duct is leaking moist air into the wall space.

Comment: Open that wall up and have a look. Show us where the dryer vents out of the house. Roof penetration is a common point for water to enter and it would follow the duct all the way to the lowest point. Inside the duct looks rusty